# How can I create a mutex in J2EE EJB

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-ee, synchronization

I'm very new to J2EE, so apologies if this is obvious.  I have to work around a bad database design, which has an update which cannot be done safely in parallel.  The easiest way to fix this (for now) is to place a mutex protection around the method call to serialize it's access.

I understand that you can't safely just use the synchronised keyword on the method in J2EE as the container may interfere.  Is there a "supported" way in J2EE to make a mutex/semaphore/lock in an EJB to ensure access to a method is serialised  for the entire J2EE application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for prosperity, the java.util.concurrent are all approved for use within the container.  Blocking using a Semaphore will work within a single container, but you will need a higher level of synchronisation to maintain synchronisation in a cluster.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a static object as the mutex, for example:

```
private static final Object mutex = new Object ();

public void someMethod() {
    synchronized(mutex) {
        // do work that must be globally synchronous
    }
}
```

The reason that using `synchronized` on the method itself won't work for you is that the Java EE container may create multiple instances of EJBs but the methods marked `synchronized` are only protected on a per-instance basis (where each instance can have only one thread executing a `synchronized` method at a time, but multiple instances can be accessed concurrently).

Comment: So I can safely assume that the static objects in a J2EE container are static across the container?  I assume this won't work across a clustered application though

Comment: If the different containers use different classloaders to load the given class, this will fail. I don't know what the solution is, but I am pretty sure this is not it.

Comment: @ILMTitan that depends on where you declare the static mutex objects. They don't need to be declared inside the EJB classes, which would then avoid the issue with multiple class loaders. Where to declare them is probably going to depend on the particular Java EE container, since different vendors may use different strategies as to which classes get loaded more than once in different class loaders.